# C++ File IO - can't find methods for File IO related stuff

Tags: c++, file, io

```
#include "Shader.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

static char* textFileRead(const char *fileName) 
{
    char* text;

    if (fileName != NULL) 
    {
        FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rt");

        if (file != NULL) 
        {
              fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
              int count = ftell(file);
              rewind(file);

            if (count > 0) 
            {
                text = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (count + 1));
                count = fread(text, sizeof(char), count, file);
                text[count] = '\0';
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

This is what I have for a shader program found in a tutorial I'm trying to follow. When I build this to check for errors, I get errors saying fopen(), fseek(), ftell(), rewind(), and fclose() isn't declared in this scope. How can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: That's definitely not a shader program.  Maybe part of a host program for setting up shaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using C file IO in a C++ program.
You included iostream.h, so use it.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Comment: It's not `iostream.h`, it's only `iostream`. And also, the file related streams are under `<fstream>`.

Comment: Or just include <cstdio> for C style IO. But using <fstream> in a C++ program is surely the better way, as said in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need add the header file for standard IO as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

or (c++ preferred)

```
#include <cstdio>
```